# Best way to retrieve items from a webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I have a WPF application that needs to retrieve around 60000 records by calling an external webservice. The webservice returns them in a HUGE json, once i receive it I need to deserialize it into my list of objects. What is the best approach for this so that this process does not take too long while loading them up ?.

Also in the same way, at some point i need to send those same records for verification, but should i do them all at the same time?

Any architectural advise would be appreciated, no need for code but some orientation is desired (tools i can use to make it more efficient etc..).

Comment: Do it in background task. If it takes considerable amount of time, add progress bar (in modal dialog or somewhere in status bar). There is no real "architectural" decisions - service must be called and that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use dispatcher for not freezing WPF UI.
2. You can use Threadpool's thread to call webservice.

Create a class for calling webservice

```
Class Source
{
    public string GetJson()
    {
    }
}
```

Create a method in your WPF `MainWindow.xaml.cs` for calling webservice class which we created above

```
private void CallWebserviceClass(Object state)
{
  //Create object for webservice class, In our case Source class
  Source obj = new Source();
  string data = obj.GetJson();

  //Use `Dispatcher` to update the UI
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(UpdateUI), data);
}


 Private void UpdateUI(string data)
 {
   //Update UI, Bind your data to WPF controls
 }

 // Call the `CallWebserviceClass` method on different thread

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallWebserviceClass);
```

Comment: This may not be architectural advise, but this one provides a basic idea for how to proceed for long running tasks in different thread and how to update the value from other thread to UI using dispatcher for that intention only i posted answer

Comment: There are dozens of such information here on StackOverflow, no need to repeat it once again.

Comment: Yes Konrad Kokosa you are right there may be dozens of such information on stack overflow.I posted answer just for giving basic idea on how to approach such scenarios. Something is better than Nothing

Comment: If using .net 4.5 an awaitable task is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, if you have scope to change the web service, you are not going to get much better than JSON. You can however look at shortening any field names in your data type so the headers in the file are minimised - I.e. If your record object contains a field like 'accountNumber' change it to 'AN' and that is 600k x 11 characters removed from the response. JSON was designed to send Ks of data, not MBs - but then what did they expect!

Next, if you can start 'verification' as soon as you get a record, consider adding paging to your service response - for example, return your records in 50k blocks so whilst the second block in downloading, you can verify the first block.

As suggested, improve the user experience by providing some feedback, be that a progress bar or status message. Making this data operation run async, can your app let the user do something else whilst it loads?

These are suggestions, you will need to measure any impact to see if it improves things.

An example of a paging in Web API with a queryable dataset:

```
    public async Task<object> GetData(int page, int pagesize)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(() =>
        {
            return dataset.Skip(page * pagesize).Take(pagesize);
        });
    }
```

... where 'object' is your record type and 'dataset' is possibly an entity framework DataSet.

Pass in the page and pagesize attributes in your request - then you can fine tune performance by adapting your pagesize. From your client, loop until the result set has less records than pagesize.

Comment: Question, is there a good example that you know of for paging responses?

Answer (score 0):

- Do it. Plain, dirty, direct.
- Measure it.
- Improve it if neccessary. Maybe by putting it in a background thread.

That's very general, but having 60K Items is a very general description. Sending 60K ints is a breeze, sending 60K structures or structured subdata including pictures is probably too much for your RAM.